# How to calculate a variable using two different sets of equations selected according a criteria from large data set in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to calculate a variable (settling velocity ) using two different sets of equations selected according a criteria from large data set using Matlab.

I load all sediment diameter (D50) values in a text file. Then I have to calculate settling velocity.

Settling velocity depends on the sediment diameter. For sand I want to use one set of equations and for silt and clay I want another set of equations. The criteria is D50 > 0.0000625.

I used if and else conditions (please see the script written by me; I am new to matlab, this may not be efficient).

However, it uses only one set of equations to calculate settling velocity. There should be a problem of writing if condition. Here is the sample data set.

```
D50=
0.0002626
0.0002626
0.000003504
0.0000108
0.0000985
```

The answer I get;

```
ws=
0.069
0.069
0.0000123
0.000117
0.009717
```

But the answer should be;

```
ws=
0.03681
0.03681
0.0000123
0.000117
0.009717
```

According to the results from following scripts, I can see that the calculations were done only using the equations after else condition. The calculations under if condition were not done. I have done calculations using only one set of equations separately. I get the write answers.

But I want to include two set of equations and do the calculations according to criteria defined here. (This calculation is only a part of large script to simulate morphological evolution due to sea-level rise for my PhD work. Previously my script included only the first set of equation but I want to improve the model using two set of equations.)

Below is my code. I am very grateful to anyone who can help me to sort out this problem.

---

```
%%% Settling velocity

g=9.81;

psed=2650;

pw=1027;

neu=0.000001004;

p=0.4;

load D50.txt

    i=1:length(D50);

    if D50(i) > 0.0000625
        Dstar=D50(i)*(g*((psed/pw)-1)/neu^2)^(1/3);
        Dstarpower=Dstar.^3; 
        j=1:length(Dstarpower); 
        idleA=ones(size(D50));   
        idleB=107.3296*idleA+1.049*Dstarpower; 
        idleC=idleB.^0.5;
        idleD=idleC-10.36*idleA; 
        idleE=neu*idleD;
        ws=idleE./D50

    else 
        ws=1000000*(D50.^2)
    end

    CoefA=ws/((1-p)*psed);

    fileID1=fopen('ws.txt','w');
    fprintf(fileID1,'%6.6f\r\n',ws);
    fclose(fileID1);

fileID2=fopen('CoefA.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID2,'%6.6f\r\n',CoefA);
fclose(fileID2);
```

Comment: We don't have a background in what you are trying to compute and so we can't verify if what you are computing is correct.  Is there some literature or something you can write further that clarifies what exactly you are trying to compute?  However, from the looks of it, those numbers that are `> 0.000625` are the only numbers that are incorrect while the other numbers match.  You should probably double check the logic / computation inside the `if` statement and see if it matches up with what you're computing mathematically.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to write a `for` loop... like `i = 1: length(D50)` and `j = 1: length(Dstarpower)`, yet your `for` constructs are missing.  As such, `i` and `j` would be vectors of a predetermined length and thus the `if` conditions won't work like how you're expecting.

Comment: Please tell me simply how to calculate certain paramter based on data loaded from a text file and two criterions.

Comment: Please tell me simply how to calculate certain paramter based on data loaded from a text file  containing all D50 values and two criterions. The first criterion: If D50> 0.0000625; then ws=3*D50+0.01, else ws=10000*(D50)^2.

Comment: What is the error in > 0.000625? I am very much grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Could any one help me to solve following issue. I want correct scripts to calculate certain parameter based on another parameter (e.g. data loaded from a text file containing all D50 values) and criterions. The first criterion: If D50> 0.0000625; then ws=3*D50+0.01, else ws=10000*(D50)^2. rayryeng, could you please tell me What is the error in > 0.000625? I am very much grateful if you can help me.